# Video Streaming using UDP VLC QT

Tags: c++, qt, video, udp, vlc

I am using the stream, a feature of the VLC player to do a video streaming.

The video format that I am streaming is in mp4 format. The destination setup of the video streaming is through udp at the ip address 127.0.0.1 and port 9000. 
There are mainly four issues I am facing:

1. During the streaming of the mp4 video, I do not see the video playing on the VLC player. It shows a black screen and I could only hear the audio of the video. If a wmv video is streamed instead, I could see the video playing as well as hearing the audio. Does the format of the video file affects streaming? Why I could not see the video playing on VLC when the mp4 file is streamed? The option of display locally is checked.
2. Also when the mwv format video is streamed, the video is very pixelated. Is there a way to make adjustment to the stream so that the video is clear.
3. Header file WinSock2.h:No such file or directory but there isn’t any build errors, program able to build.
4. How do I go about connecting my udp client to the VLC video stream so that I could receive the video file that is being stream on the VLC player and display it in a QMediaPlayer. I am using c++ and Qt creator.

My udp code are as follows:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<winsock2.h>

#pragma comment(lib,"ws2_32.lib") //Winsock Library

#define SERVER "127.0.0.1"  
#define BUFLEN 512  
#define PORT 9000   

int main(void)
{
    struct sockaddr_in si_other;
    int s; 
    int slen=sizeof(si_other);
    char buf[BUFLEN];
    char message[BUFLEN];
    WSADATA wsa;

    //Initialise winsock
    printf("\nInitialising Winsock");
    if (WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2,2),&wsa) != 0)
    {
        printf("Failed. Error Code : %d",WSAGetLastError());
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    printf("Initialised.\n");

    //create socket
    if ( (s=socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, IPPROTO_UDP)) == SOCKET_ERROR)
    {
        printf("socket() failed with error code : %d" , WSAGetLastError());
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    //setup address structure
    memset((char *) &si_other, 0, sizeof(si_other));
    si_other.sin_family = AF_INET;
    si_other.sin_port = htons(PORT);
    si_other.sin_addr.S_un.S_addr = inet_addr(SERVER);
     closesocket(s);
    WSACleanup();

    return 0;
}
```

Please advice. Thanks